# Можно ли править добавить данные в JS файл через админку?

Tags: javascript, php, html

У меня есть файл - track.js в котором массивы номеров и их значений.

```js
const tracks = {
  '5678':  {"Delivery": "22.03.2021", "Name": "Alex", "City": "Moscow"},
  '6678':  {"Delivery": "12.03.2021", "Name": "Bell", "City": "New York"},
  '7678':  {"Delivery": "182.03.2021", "Name": "Mike", "City": "Berlin"},
};
```

Есть ли возможность сделать страницу (возможно на пхп), куда можно будет добавить номер и все дополнительные данные, для более удобной работы простого юзера?

Comment: А что конкретно юзер собирается делать с этими номерами и данными?

Comment: это не для юзера, для админа. Он должен иметь возможность добавлять новые данные, но привычным способом)

Comment: Можно, но грамотнее и лучше будет, если  получать эти данные из `.json` и изменение вводить в `.json`

Comment: @AlexLvl Понятно, админ=юзер. Возможность есть, только это `страница+JS`->`запрос`->`обработка_сервером`->`чтение_или_запись`->`JSON_или_DB`->`ответ`->`и_так_по_кругу` - сложно это представить вопросом для SO.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже написали в комментариях, в Вашем случае лучше хранить эти данные не прямо в коде в виде массивов, а в какой-нибудь БД или txt-файле (но лучше БД). Соответственно схема добавления такая:

**index.html** (страничка для админа)

```html
<form method="POST" action="add.php">
  <input name="input_1" type="text">
  <!--Все нужные данные берём-->
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

**add.php** (связь с БД)

```php
<?php
$input_1_data = $_POST['input_1'];
//Получили все данные
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO `table_name`(`field_1`) VALUES ('".$input_1_data."')";
if (mysql_query($sql_query)) echo "OK"; else echo "Error";
?>
```

Всё это можно оформить гораздо красивее и большим количеством способов, но данный пример призван лишь показать путь решения.